# HttpClient and Client Certificate error

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am implementing a REST api call using System.Net...HttpClient over ssl. I have been given the client certificate. I store the client certificate in the bin folder of the executable of the app (the app is a console app.) So in my code I read the client certificate like this:

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
    {
        try
        {
            return new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(_certificateLocation),
                _certificatePassword);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And also I ignore SSL errors as follow before the request:

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender,
            certificate,
            chain,
            errors) => true;
```

I send the http request by using this code:

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
var cert = GetClientCertificate();
 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                var resp = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(_apiEndPoint), content);
                resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
.........
.........
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while sending the request.:: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Can someone assist me?

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `cert`.

Comment: Missing line `handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);`

Comment: I have that line added to it.

Comment: Are you running your code through IIS by any chance?